# How to mark sharp by angle?

Tags: uv

I try to mark sharp, but I found the only way is to select it one by one and mark in edge menu, is there a way to do it by angle just like auto smooth or edge split?

and then I want to turn sharp into seam , how to do it??

Answer (score 14):

You can do this easily using the *Select Sharp Edges* function.

1. Use *Select > Select Sharp Edges* and adjust the angle.
2. Now you can mark all selected edges as sharp

To turn all sharp eges into UV seams.

1. Select one sharp edge
2. Use *Select > Similar > Sharpness* and mark the edges as seams

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know you can adjust angle with select sharp edge !

Comment: @YoungGilgamesh Honestly, I didn't know it either before this question :).